# Why does drupal use .yml and not officially recommended .yaml

Tags: 8

Per yaml page https://yaml.org/faq.html they recommend .yaml as file extension but I see drupal uses almost exclusively .yml, how so? And does adding .yaml to file extension even work for drupal 8 or will it be skipped?

Comment: Probably because of Symfony - they didn't support the .yaml extension until later on (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/6727a2610bb5070394dd269089b1616a9207537e). I'd imagine Drupal just went along with what was available at the time. Incidentally: no, the .yaml extension doesn't work with Drupal as of 8.6.5

Answer (score 3):

Drupal uses '.yml' because Symfony uses '.yml'

This was discussed in https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2091669

I am assuming that '.yaml' would not work, but I haven't tried it. For consistency reasons it is best to stick to '.yml'.

EDIT: Looks like Symfony has started recommending '.yaml' from version 4.0. Can be seen by comparing this page https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/routing.html with the 3.4 version

Comment: I remember now I got one occasion where I used .yaml and d8 module didnt work. I was surprised as my code editor was enforcing .yaml as extension and I didnt think it would matter, but it did.

Answer (score -1):

because drupal 8 based on symfony 2 and .yaml is not recomended in symfony 2 , it's recomended just for version 4 of symfony 4